# Getting all elements in list with certain attribute value in python - Improved solution compared to loop

Tags: python

In my python-based project I have the following problem: I have a list with many entries, with each entry being an object of the same class. This is demonstrated in the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class demo_class:
    """Example class for demonstration"""
    def __init__(self, val_a, val_b, val_c):
        self.val_a = val_a
        self.val_b = val_b
        self.val_c = val_c

    def print_something(self):
        """Foo-function, executed for demonstration"""
        print(str(self.val_a) + ", " + str(self.val_b) + ", " + str(self.val_c))

#Data generation
list_of_demo_classes = []
for i in range(0, 2):
    for j in range(0, 2):
        for k in range(0, 2):
            local_demo_class = demo_class(val_a = i, val_b = j, val_c = k)
            list_of_demo_classes.append(local_demo_class)
```

Now I would first select all elements where `val_a = 0` and `val_b = 0`, afterwards all elements where `val_a = 0` and `val_b = 1`, and so on, until I have called all entries in the list. The current approach is

```
#How can I optimize this?
for i in range(0, 2):
    for j in range(0, 2):
        for k in range(0, 2):
            for elem in list_of_demo_classes:
                if elem.val_a != i:
                    continue
                if elem.val_b != j:
                    continue
                if elem.val_c != k:
                    continue
                elem.print_something()
```

but this approach does look rather brute-force for me. Are there better solutions?

Comment: Hey I'm afraid this is too hypothetical to be reviewed? You might need list comprehensions, maybe? Can't say without the complete code.

Comment: @kubatucka: This is my full code broken down to an MWE. What I basically want is: "Get all elements from list `list_of_demo_classes` for which `val_a == i` and `val_b == j`, and then iterate over all possible entries for `val_a` and `val_b`". My current approach is shown above, but it looks inefficient to me.

Comment: "_Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site._"  Minimal Working Examples are for **Stack Overflow**.  At **Code Review**, we want actual code, so we can provide a real review.  For instance `demo_class` is a horrible class name for several reasons, but creating a review for that is meaningless since it isn't a real class name.

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell — based more on your code's behavior than your description of it — you have some objects and you want to print them all in an
order based on their attribute values. If so, a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) could help by
eliminating most of the boilerplate code and by supporting attribute-based
sorting directly (via `order = True`). Here's a brief demonstration:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from random import randint

@dataclass(order = True)
class Element:
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int

elements = [
    Element(randint(1, 3), randint(0, 2), randint(0, 2))
    for _ in range(10)
]

for e in sorted(elements):
    print(e)
```

Output from one run:

```
Element(a=1, b=0, c=1)
Element(a=1, b=2, c=2)
Element(a=2, b=2, c=1)
Element(a=2, b=2, c=1)
Element(a=2, b=2, c=2)
Element(a=3, b=0, c=0)
Element(a=3, b=1, c=1)
Element(a=3, b=1, c=2)
Element(a=3, b=2, c=1)
Element(a=3, b=2, c=1)
```